# Dynamic placeHolders

Tags: modx, modx-chunks

I would like ask, if anyone knows how can I make a dynamic placeholders using an array. Basically I have this structure, and need to create a placeholders where the "name" has the "content"

```
{
  "name": "bigTitle",
  "type": "text",
  "content": "Got a question?"
}
```

[return placeholders with the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zCa8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [toPlaceholders](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extending-modx/modx-class/reference/modx.toplaceholders) method here, use can create own custom snippet/plugin (depends on how do you really use it) and run this this method inside.

Comment: Thank for taking your time to answer me. It was very useful

Comment: Nps, @AndresPerez please mark answer as "solution" or "useful" if it really helped you. Thanks!